# Parallelizing with joblib - Clarity

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, joblib

I've been searching for the last couple of hours, and I can't quite get my head around how to do this - I'm new to the world of parallel computing.

My task: I wish to update a particular value (or three) on an array of particles. Currently, I have a function that does something like:

```
def velocity_update(particle_array, Field1, Field2)
    for n in range(N)
        particle_array[0,n] = # vx equation
        particle_array[1,n] = # vy equation
        particle_array[2,n] = # vz equation
return particle_array
```

Where particle array contains the attributes of each particle (position, velocity, etc.) for N particles in a 2D numpy array. Field1 and Field2 are fields acting on these particles, but the particles do not effect each other or the fields, so these are just other arrays serving as lookup tables.

My question: How can I use joblib to parallelize this loop? Would I have to remove the loop from the function and iterate in the main program (sending only one column of my array for the specific particle, rather than the whole array), or is there a way to parallelize within the function so I can still return my updated particle array? I know it seems inefficient to copy the whole array each time, but the position of the particles is also important - so I need all the data on the particles (though I'm only changing the velocities).

Usually I'd have a play around with it, but at the moment I'm struggling to understand how to even apply it to provide sample code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I googled to how to implement parallel computing using joblib and found this [link](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) on joblib parallel class. I hope this could solve your problem.

All the best!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've read that page and most others on Google. The problem is that I don't understand how to apply the parallelization process to this particular problem - a function with a loop in it, where it's the loop that I want to parallelize. Joblib seems to only like functions.

Comment: `def parallel_looping(number):
    data = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(number))
    return data`

See in this example loop is being parallelized

Comment: In this case, I'm particularly troubled by how to handle the output. The information on the particles is contained in a matrix. I need to be able to update the velocity of each particle using the information in this matrix, then *store* it in the appropriate section of the matrix.

In this case, the solution doesn't seem immediately apparent to me, and copying the examples from google (which I've read) sadly doesn't help.